# Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadError Failure m

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have defined a custom error type:

```
data Failure = NetworkError Message |
               UserIsTooStupid Message |
               InvalidOperation Message |
               UnexpectedError Message
type Message = String
```

I am trying to use [`MonadError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t%3aMonadError) with my error type:

```
loadJSON :: (Aeson.FromJSON v, MonadIO m, MonadError Failure m) => URI -> m v
loadJSON uri = do
    body <- liftIO $ getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest uri)
    case Aeson.decode body of
         Just json -> return json
         Nothing -> throwError $ SerialisationError "Couldn't deserialise from JSON"

type URI = String
```

In other words, this function can return any monad which satisfies both `MonadIO` and `MonadError`, but the only type of error it can throw is `Failure`.

This fails to compile, with the error message:

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadError Failure m
(Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)
In the type signature for `loadJSON':
  loadJSON :: (Aeson.FromJSON v, MonadIO m, MonadError Failure m) =>
              URI -> m v
```

GHC wants me to turn on the `FlexibleContexts` language extension to make this code work. What does `FlexibleContexts` do, and is it *really* necessary in my case? I prefer not to turn on language extensions willy-nilly without knowing whether I need them.

The function compiles fine if I leave off the type signature, but I prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Haskell 98 doesn't allow constraints that looks like `MonadError Failure m`, they have to look like `MonadError a m`. The ability to have constraints like that was added to GHC however, which is what that extension does. I understand being wary of language extensions, but FlexibleContexts is pretty harmless.

I believe at the time Haskell 98 came out, the type theory to use constraints like that hadn't been developed, but since then it has. The extension turns on some extra code in the type checker which uses that theory. If you google around a little you might be able to find a paper on how it works.

Comment: Could you you elaborate a little more on what the language extension does? In what sense is it harmless? Why does Haskell 98 disallow such type signatures?

Comment: It is harmless in the sense that is does not change the meaning of programs which do not use that extension, and assigns a "sensible" meaning to those that do use it. A few other extensions such as `IncoherentInstances` are instead regarded as potentially harmful since programs exploiting them have a tricky semantics, hence they are hard to reason about.