# lift Either to ExceptT automatically

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, either, lifting

Let's say I have this (arguably mislead) piece of code laying around:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import Control.Monad.Except

parseArgs :: ExceptT String IO User
parseArgs =
  do
    args <- lift getArgs
    case safeHead args of
      Just admin -> parseUser admin
      Nothing    -> throwError "No admin specified"

parseUser :: String -> Either String User
-- implementation elided

safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
-- implementation elided

main =
  do
    r <- runExceptT parseArgs
    case r of
      Left  err -> putStrLn $ "ERROR: " ++ err
      Right res -> print res
```

`ghc` gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘ExceptT String IO User’
            with actual type ‘Either String User’
In the expression: parseUser admin
In a case alternative: Just admin -> parseUser admin
```

What's the most standard way of lifting an `Either` into an `ExceptT`?
I feel there must be some way since `Either String` is an instance of `MonadError`.

I wrote my own lifting function:

```
liftEither :: (Monad m, MonadError a (Either a)) => Either a b -> ExceptT a m b
liftEither = either throwError return
```

But to me this still feels wrong since I'm already working inside the
`ExceptT` monad transformer.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I structure my code differently?

Comment: What about `ExceptT . return`? `ExceptT = ExceptT (m (Either e a))`, so `return` gets you to `IO (Either String User)` and `ExceptT` (as constructor/function) to `ExceptT String IO User`.

Comment: Your `liftEither` sounds like the right answer to me (or Cactus's answer about generalizing the type of `parseUser`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generalise `parseUser`'s type to

```
parseUser :: (MonadError String m) => String -> m User
```

and then it would work both at `m ~ Either String` and at `m ~ ExceptT String m'` (if only `Monad m'`) without any manual lifting necessary.

The way to do it is to basically replace `Right` with `return` and `Left` with `throwError` in `parseUser`'s definition.

Comment: Note that for the contraint `MonadError String m` ghc needs the `FlexibleContexts` extension (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22795830/905686).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `transformers` instead of `mtl`, then you can use [`tryRight`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.3.0/docs/Control-Error-Safe.html#v:tryRight) from `Control.Error.Safe`.

```
tryRight :: Monad m => Either e a -> ExceptT e m a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `except` in `transformers` (Control.Monad.Trans.Except):

[`except :: Monad m => Either e a -> ExceptT e m a`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.5/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:except)

It is defined as ibotty suggested in a comment.

It's a bit different from your `liftEither`, since it doesn't `MonadError`. You can use it anywhere where ExceptT is applicable.

BTW, there is already a `liftEither`, which is different:

[`liftEither :: MonadError e m => Either e a -> m a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:liftEither).

I don't think this one is useful for you here.